# Is there any documentation for omitting zeroes in dot-decimal notation of IPv4 addresses?

Tags: ipv4, rfc

I’ve noticed that Linux and *BSD systems allow user to skip octets when using dot-decimal notation.

Here are some examples:

```
$ ping 10.1
PING 10.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

$ ping 10.15.1
PING 10.15.1 (10.15.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Note that this isn’t limited to the ping command.

I’ve found document defining textual representations of IPv4, but it doesn’t seem to cover that feature: [Textual Representation of IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-main-ipaddr-text-rep-00).

Is there any other document defining this behavior? Is there a specific name for this behavior?

Comment: it's possible that this isn't part of the standard, but instead a short cut in the specific applications. it could be widespread and a de facto standard, but maybe not official?

Comment: I found http://www.linuxsa.org.au/pipermail/linuxsa/2007-September/088131.html moderately insightful. It links to http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-main-ipaddr-text-rep-02 for the "full saga".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [`inet_aton()` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton).
The last part is the numerical value representing the contents of the remaining bits in the address, i.e., a 24-bit `y` in `x.y`, and a 16-bit `z` in `x.y.z`.

Answer (score -1):

Abbreviated prefixes.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3779

> prefix - a bit string that consists of some number of initial bits of
> an address, written as an address followed by a "/", and the
> number of initial bits.  10.5.0.0/16 and 2001:0:200:3:0:0:0:0/64
> (or 2001:0:200:3::/64) are examples of prefixes.  A prefix is
> often abbreviated by omitting the less-significant zero fields,
> but there should be enough fields to contain the indicated number
> of initial bits.  10.5/16 and 2001:0:200:3/64 are examples of
> abbreviated prefixes.

Comment: The question did not ask about prefixes. There is no "/" in the question.