# Incomplete IP address are filled with zeroes

Tags: linux, ipv4

I have realized that in Linux (RHEL and Debian) incomplete IPv4 address in dot notation are filled with inner zeroes. For example I typed 172.30.122 instead of 172.30.0.122 but Linux corrected and used 172.30.0.122

```
# ping 172.30.107  

PING 172.30.107 (172.30.0.107) 56(84) bytes of data.  
64 bytes from 172.30.0.107: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=2.19 ms  
64 bytes from 172.30.0.107: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=1.18 ms
```

At least two bytes are required -- the missing inner bytes are not needed:

```
# ping 172.107  
PING 172.107 (172.0.0.107) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Is this a bug?
Does the standards allow that?

Thanx in advance

Comment: This is standard behaviour across operating systems, Windows does the same, whether it is part of the TCP/IP standard I do not know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any documentation for omitting zeroes in dot-decimal notation of IPV4 addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133820/is-there-any-documentation-for-omitting-zeroes-in-dot-decimal-notation-of-ipv4-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate question since it was answered before, maybe some more research and you would find the answer :D

There's a Stack Overflow question asking something similar ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133820/is-there-any-documentation-for-ommiting-zeroes-in-dot-decimal-notation-of-ipv4-a)).

The main reason is how inet_aton() ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton)) converts the octets into the binary address.